# Error con los estilos en mi página de error 404

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, error404

Tengo mi página de error 404 ubicada en `public_html/404.html` conectada con una hoja de estilos con ubicación relativa, como cualquier otra página; y tengo una regla en mi .htaccess ubicado en `public_html/.htaccess` que dice que la página antes mencionada es la del error 404:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Todo está bien en primera instancia. Daré el ejemplo justamente en el sitio web donde está el fallo.

Háblese de tratar de acceder a una página inexistente que está ubicada en el mismo lugar que la página 404:

[tmnwtools.000webhostapp.com/hola](https://tmnwtools.000webhostapp.com/hola)

Ahí todo está bien.
El problema viene cuando trato de acceder a una página inexistente que está colocada en una carpeta más profunda que donde la página 404 se ubica:

[tmnwtools.000webhostapp.com/hola/mundo](https://tmnwtools.000webhostapp.com/hola/mundo)

Al entrar a una página inexistente ubicada en otra carpeta más adentro, el documento HTML de error 404 es servido, pero la hoja de estilos ya no está conectada a la página 404, haciendo que esta quede sin estilo CSS. Puedo intuir que se trata de un error de referencia y el documento HTML busca la hoja de estilos donde la página inexistente a servir y que por eso ya no se encuentra.

¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de arreglarlo?

Gracias y espero que me puedas ayudar. Si necesitas más información, la subiré.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es que la primera web está enlazando con la hoja de estilos styles.css situada en la misma carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero la segunda URL no está enlazada con ninguna hoja de estilos, está enlazada con un "styles.css", pero ese styles.css no es una hoja de estilos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basicamente el problema es que la ruta de la hoja de estilos de la segunda URL está mal, si quieres que pille los mismos estilos que la otra cambia la ruta asi:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style.css" />
```

Comment: El problema es que estamos hablando de una página que no existe. Lo que falla es que no atrapa los estilos al redireccionar a la 404 desde más abajo y no puedo cambiar public_html/hola porque no existe.

Answer (score 0):

espero que estés bien. Me pasó tambien lo solucioné colocando los estilos dentro del mismo documento html.

O sea, puedes dentro del head abrir una etiqueta style y colocar allí los estilos css, así siempre se mantendrá el estilo.

Importante, si la página tiene un enlace para redireccionar al home. Usa como href la url del sitio no lo coloques como "index.html" por ejemplo.

No es la mejor práctica poner los estilos de esta manera, pero te da una solución temporal y simple mientras sigues averiguando como hacerlo